# how to add a custom listView to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-listfragment

i'm trying to a custom listview in my fragment but getting a null-pointer error, how can i fix this.. i'm a beginner.

listmain.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
       android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my main activity this is for a navigation drawer:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#009933")));
        //getActionBar().setIcon(
               // new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment(this);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

this is my fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Activity activity;
    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    public View rootView;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public HomeFragment(Activity acticity){

        this.activity=activity;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listmain, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color


        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidePDialog();

                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                        movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating")).doubleValue());
                        movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                        // Genre is json array
                        JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                        ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {

                            genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                        }
                        movie.setGenre(genre);

                        // adding movie to movies array
                        movieList.add(movie);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {

        if (pDialog != null) {

            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my customadapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    //public Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter( Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
        //this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {

        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        // rating
        rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

        // genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {

            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0, genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

my log:

---

```
11-25 06:41:20.813: W/dalvikvm(1135): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c18648)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.listadapter.CustomListAdapter.<init>(CustomListAdapter.java:28)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:57)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5142)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
11-25 06:41:20.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling customListAdapter before your JSON processing has happened. So the movielist that you are passing to customListAdapter does not have any value. That is why you are getting a null pointer exception.

Solution: Execute this line of code after your JSON processing is complete

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Best way of doing what you are trying is to use an AsyncTask to fetch the data from Server, and in the onPostExecute method of AsyncTask, you execute the line

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: it didn't work.. i've also added my mainactivity code please do look at it

Comment: i dont think thats the cause because later everytime the json is parsed im notifying the adapter

Comment: Have you put the required array in R.array.nav_drawer_items? I hope that is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Initially your `movieList` is null there is no any data.

```
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

you just need to move your above code in `onResponse()` method rather than `onCreateView()` method. So its looks like

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {.....
             adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
             listView.setAdapter(adapter);
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }.......
```

In this method your data and UI will be updated.

Comment: Now at which line it shows a error? Show your activity_main.xml file too

Comment: i've added my activity_main.xml

Comment: Sorry. post listmain.xml file instead of activity_main.xml. please

Comment: i have added listmain.xml

Comment: Your class extends with ListFragment then you need to use setListAdapter(adapter); method. Further more check http://www.perfectapk.com/android-listfragment-tutorial.html

Comment: i tried using that too.. still getting the same error

Comment: Okay. Show me that line at where you'r getting error

Comment: give me your mail address i shall mail you the whole code